# Em redações oficiais. Qual a diferença entre pronome de tratamento e vocativo?

Tags: significado, diferenças, sintaxe, concordância

Segundo o manual de redações oficiais do Brasil os pronomes de tratamento em redações oficiais são os seguintes:

Vossa Excelência, para as seguintes autoridades:

**a) do Poder Executivo:**
Presidente da República;
Vice-Presidente da República;
Ministros de Estado;
Governadores e Vice-Governadores de Estado e do Distrito Federal;
Oficiais-Generais das Forças Armadas;
Embaixadores;
Secretários-Executivos de Ministérios e demais ocupantes de cargos de natureza especial;
Secretários de Estado dos Governos Estaduais;
Prefeitos Municipais.

**b) do Poder Legislativo:**
Deputados Federais e Senadores;
Ministro do Tribunal de Contas da União;
Deputados Estaduais e Distritais;
Conselheiros dos Tribunais de Contas Estaduais;
Presidentes das Câmaras Legislativas Municipais.

**c) do Poder Judiciário:**
Ministros dos Tribunais Superiores;
Membros de Tribunais;
Juízes;
Auditores da Justiça Militar.

**No entanto o vocativo é diferente.**

O vocativo a ser empregado em comunicações dirigidas aos Chefes de Poder é Excelentíssimo Senhor, seguido do cargo respectivo:

Excelentíssimo Senhor Presidente da República,
Excelentíssimo Senhor Presidente do Congresso Nacional,
Excelentíssimo Senhor Presidente do Supremo Tribunal Federal.

As demais autoridades serão tratadas com o vocativo Senhor, seguido do cargo respectivo:

Senhor Senador,
Senhor Juiz,
Senhor Ministro,
Senhor Governador,

**Por que neste caso usamos o vocativo "Excelentíssimo Senhor" para algumas autoridades e "Senhor" para outras?**

**Em redações oficiais, qual a diferença entre pronome de tratamento e vocativo?**

Fonte: [Manual de Redação da Presidência da República [do Brasil]](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/manual/manual.htm)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Por que neste caso usamos o vocativo "Excelentíssimo Senhor" para algumas autoridades e "Senhor" para outras?**

Segundo o link contido na pergunta, usamos os vocativos `como expediente lingüístico de distinção e de respeito`. Ao dirirgimo-nos a cargos mais elevados, portanto, demonstramos ainda mais distinção e respeito através do adjetivo "excelentíssimo".

---

**Em redações oficiais, qual a diferença entre pronome de tratamento e vocativo?**

> Pronome de tratamento, axiónimo (português europeu) ou axiônimo (português brasileiro) é a palavra que auxilia em uma linguagem mais formal empregada da mesma maneira que os pronomes pessoais. [[Wikipédia]](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronome_de_tratamento)

Ou seja, utiliza-se um pronome de tratamento no lugar dos pronomes pessoais informais. Os pronomes de tratamento também exigem que conjuguemos os verbos na terceira pessoa, ao invés da segunda. É uma maneira de se dirigir ao interlocutor indiretamente.

Trocando em miúdos, é uma maneira de tratar certas pessoas sem utilizar o **tu** ou o **você**.

> Vocativo é o termo da oração por meio do qual chamamos ou interpelamos o nosso interlocutor [...]  [[Wikipédia]](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocativo)

Portanto, o vocativo é utilizado quando o emissor da mensagem (quem escreve) se dirige diretamente ao receptor (quem lê).

---

## Exemplos

Nos exemplos abaixo (baseados no [manual incluso na pergunta](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/manual/manual.htm)), o locutor começa por usar um vocativo para chamar a atenção do interlocutor:

> João, tu vais ao mercado hoje?

Suponhamos agora que queremos tratar o João de forma mais cerimoniosa e formal.O vocativo *João* é substituído por um vocativo mais cerimonioso, e o pronome pessoal *tu* é igualmente substituído por um pronome de tratamento cerimonioso:

> Excelentíssimo Senhor João, Vossa Excelência vai ao mercado hoje? *(Caso João seja um Chefe de Poder)*
>
> Magnífico Senhor João, Vossa Magnificência vai ao mercado hoje? *(Caso João seja um Reitor)*
>
> Reverendíssimo Senhor João, Vossa Reverência vai ao mercado hoje? *(Caso João seja um Padre)*
>
> Senhor João, Vossa Senhoria vai ao mercado hoje? *(Outros)*

*Nota: Os exemplos acima são apenas uma seleção de alguns pronomes de tratamento e vocativos.*

*Nota 2: Repare que foi necessário alterar a conjugação do verbo ir, mudando-o de* vais *para* vai*.*

Answer (score 3):

Sendo duas perguntas, acredito que a 2ª (sobre diferença entre pronome de tratamento e vocativo) está plenamente respondida pelo @Bell App Lab.

Quanto à 1ª pergunta (**Por que neste caso usamos o vocativo "Excelentíssimo Senhor" para algumas autoridades e "Senhor" para outras?**), certamente é cabível responder que se deve a um pressuposto de maior respeito devido às autoridades designadas como "Excelentíssimo(/a) Senhor(a)". Por outro lado, o manual citado (Manual de Redação da Presidência da República) é obrigatório apenas para o Poder Executivo da esfera federal brasileira. Os governos estaduais e municipais do país, por exemplo, não estão vinculados a esse manual e podem adotar outros vocativos e escalas hierárquicas.

Além disso, no âmbito do Poder Judiciário, o vocativo "Excelentíssimo Senhor" é utilizado para as autoridades de todos os níveis, abrangendo juízes de primeiro grau, desembargadores e ministros de tribunais superiores. Vide por exemplo [este artigo](http://amdjus.com.br/Noticias/artigos/005.htm), que cita o manual *CAMPESTRINI, Hildebrando e FLORENCE, Celso Barbosa. Como redigir petição inicial. São Paulo: Saraiva, 2002*.

No [Manual de Redação da PUC-RS](http://pucrs.br/manualred/tratamento.php), para dar outro exemplo, fica estabelecido o uso de "Excelentíssimo Senhor" para diversas autoridades judiciárias (Curadores, Defensores Públicos, Desembargadores, Membros de Tribunais, Procuradores, Promotores, Juízes de Direito), além de Reitores e Vice-Reitores de Universidades, Oficiais Generais, Ministros, Secretários de Estado, Cônsules, entre outros.